# Setting points in a map in R with ggplot and ggmap

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I have been trying to plot the location of penguins around Antarctica. I have been able to plot the map, but when I try to overlay the point with penguin locations the values are removed. 
I get the error

```
Removed 70 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
```

My values all seem to be within the bounds of the map.

Here is my code:

```
library(ggmap)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap)
library(maps)
library(mapdata)
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

bari <- structure(list(x = 1:6, long = c(-66.5, -62.12, -60.38, -54.25, 
-66.15, -22.58), lati = c(163, 58.07, 45.14, 22.8, 67.35, 18.21
), group = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), order = 1:6, region = c("Pygoscelis adeliae", 
"Pygoscelis adeliae", "Pygoscelis adeliae", "Pygoscelis adeliae", 
"Pygoscelis adeliae", "Spheniscus demersus"), subregion = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("x", "long", "lati", "group", 
"order", "region", "subregion"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

attach(bari)
peng <- data.frame(long,lat,region,group,order,AsNumeric = TRUE)
world <- map_data("world") 
worldmap <- ggplot(world, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group)) + 
geom_path() + 
scale_y_continuous(breaks=(-2:2) * 30) + 
scale_x_continuous(breaks=(-4:4) * 45)  
worldmap + geom_point(data=peng,aes(x=long, y=lat),pch=21,size=5,colour=NA) + coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,300)) + coord_map("ortho", orientation=c(-90, 0, 0)) 

Warning message:
Removed 70 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Your code looks correct, I suspect it is a problem with your dataset, miss-formatted, incorrect column headers, etc.  Can you provide a sample of your data?

Comment: I included a url link in the read.csv for ease

Comment: It is better to include the data in your question than expect people to click some random link.  For example `dput(head(bari))` will provide a reproducible structure of the first 10 rows of the dataframe.

Comment: @Dave2e How would I put that in the code for the question?

Comment: This statement `worldmap + geom_point(data=peng,aes(x=long, y=lat),pch=21,size=5,colour=NA)`  Color can't be NA.  Set it some color and it should work